# Does razor.servicestack support [OutputCache] (as would be used in MVC3) or something similar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, servicestack

What is the suggested way to implement output caching of service responses when using http://razor.servicestack.net?

Comment: Been awhile so figured I'll follow up on this and see if it spurs some interest.  Is there any way to do this declaratively, like via attributes, or is it something that needs to be handled service side manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not used it since it's 4.5 and our current projects are 4.0, but perhaps [CacheStack](https://github.com/jgeurts/cachestack) may be of use?

Otherwise handle it yourself via wrapping existing services with the `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` extension method, and manually expiring cache keys on CRUD type operations.

Comment: Right, razor views are cached the same way as every other format is, i.e. by using [ToOptimizedResultUsingCache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching#cache-a-response-of-a-service)